# Display Image From Ajax Response

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, image

mshafnas
OP
Posted 1 hour ago
Display Image From Ajax Response
Hi developers, I am getting the image from ajax response with the header content-type image/jpeg, I would like to display it using the img tag. when I append the src of image to the response. it is not displaying the image.

the response having some weird text and symbols.

can any one guide me to solve this issue. thanks.

below is the response

����JFIF��C

%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(��C

(((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((��R"�������=����^�yעu臝z!�^�yע��=�D<��:�Cν�G�z!�^�yעu臝z!�^�yף�ν�D<����^�yעu��D<��:�Cν�D<��:�Cν�D<��:�Cν8Ȉ�G�y�=,�ـJ�$�N9(&`$�����Ǚ�z�%D� &amp;bH��$  �d��I   35�^;�&amp;$�� t'��-T{칩�@���ݏ���lTq�|�:������(�6�<��s��&quot;H���<Ǻ�~�Me���zCv>R��(�Ǟ�=S���9��hCG�=�X���<W�'_}�#k�z�CA��&quot;$�����ژ��x|�<yyaMx|����Pgy���^���S�:JX���9=�WNG����7WvbV�?'�e$U[T�{�x�lG���\�ܗ'O��Ϗ��?{��S��=����O.=M���{4����^h=�Ϗ�PvuW���\vL�e&quot;&amp;   @�B`�������
zk�#��}$����z< ����?I2���(}o���2�.�u�?����V�g5��<��gG���$
�j���_�ǔ��8��~c�>7����W}����z/0^qh�2���ǲ���<Ǩ�?G1����f{A�y��u�~�m�� 4�'���«+(<��Ǵ�ϫ��;jm,I���x�k��5m9��5�%���O����v�xq��x�gXP�~�bG�����z0;�_����2��尡�����ُ�8�=���5>ˠ�������/���y�|��gdl    �   D�B$�"`$BD8��HG��,��   �($�!&quot;!  ��(�&amp;q�q�&amp;D&amp;b��(A(�(�I�d�#$�HP1�>�&amp;q�P&amp; J$��L8��%��2c$�J$�He�D�3&quot;q&amp;bI�,@$f   ��q����$f$D���1&quot;2�@&quot;`LILIL    ��`�LLM.ʸ�=�q5�1A����w��-�R\����
��w?����U]����E��|��S�]M�Vr�S�]3G؝��%�Wc]}>s���*��~�K=��%��Q�[���x���Z)r��O,z��W���1�겲�W��B�,TJ��۔p�[�[�v���ۮ��/�qv�E7w^�G\\�l���8�nָ�c�Uo���׮4nەj�-[׿}�y����Of'$v��_N����-��>>�N^�����ڼ��Lh�Ձ��;l���ɳ����t�Q�mql�C��p,  �o#z��؊\o5җ�i��nb��8���Y�[�9k�u�;m�*�;�M�W�Ew-��K\�w�G��“��jy����G��''%����TtY�Z8� ����J�Ġ�ۼ����Req���m�M�ײ8�n��u�G�����u�.���m֘U.v�S�d@�� ȂX�%�����@��"@�D�D� (���&$A3���ȂX���0�$Hb2c$���8�L  k�8�I�Uy3c����1 L@Ɉ���f��&bC�� �X����   ����1�X�Ĉ���B&�9�)�DL
nn�3�ہ�w?9�i[���Ϩ���hV؝�[�#���Ó�����p�

Coding

```
function base64Encode(str) {
        var CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
        var out = "", i = 0, len = str.length, c1, c2, c3;
        while (i < len) {
            c1 = str.charCodeAt(i++) & 0xff;
            if (i == len) {
                out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
                out += CHARS.charAt((c1 & 0x3) << 4);
                out += "==";
                break;
            }
            c2 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
            if (i == len) {
                out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
                out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3)<< 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
                out += CHARS.charAt((c2 & 0xF) << 2);
                out += "=";
                break;
            }
            c3 = str.charCodeAt(i++);
            out += CHARS.charAt(c1 >> 2);
            out += CHARS.charAt(((c1 & 0x3) << 4) | ((c2 & 0xF0) >> 4));
            out += CHARS.charAt(((c2 & 0xF) << 2) | ((c3 & 0xC0) >> 6));
            out += CHARS.charAt(c3 & 0x3F);
        }
        return out;
    }
    
    var token = "{{$token}}";
    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/v1/upkeep/notes/image/get/1',
        // dataType: 'image/jpeg',
        headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer '+token
            },
        method: 'GET',
        success:function(response){
            $('#image-note').attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64Encode(response));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a binary file response, in your case an image file. You can just use this URL directly as the `src` of your image, no need for an ajax request.

---

To use the content of this request directly on an image, you can base64 encode this content and set it directly as the src attribute like so:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{BASE64 STRING}}" />
```

Comment: the url is not public, we need jwt token to access it.

Comment: You can use the content directly if you base64 encode the content. I have updated my answer.

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/f39/QAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD9/QBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj9/QBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj9/QARCAQAAlIDASIAAhEBAxEB/f0AGwABAAIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEFAgMEBgf9/QAWAQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAQL9/QAMAwEAAhADEAAAAv0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA" alt="" id="image-note">

Comment: It is not displaying the image even after base64 encode

Comment: @shafnaz could you please edit your question to include the code you've written to base64 encode the response and set it to the `src`, as that's where the problem now lies

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added my coding

Comment: Would it be possible to base64 encode the image on the server-side? This would be way cleaner and more performant.

Answer (score 0):

I had used the following code. it is working fine.

```
var image_ids = {!! json_encode($note->images->toArray()) !!};



if (image_ids.length > 0) {
    var image_html = '';
    image_ids.forEach(element => {
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.open("GET", "/api/v1/upkeep/notes/image/get/"+element.id, true);
            oReq.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Bearer '+token);
            // use multiple setRequestHeader calls to set multiple values
            oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";
            oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
            var arrayBuffer = oReq.response; // Note: not oReq.responseText
            if (arrayBuffer) {
                var u8 = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
                var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
                var mimetype="image/png"; // or whatever your image mime type is
                document.getElementById("img-"+element.id).src="data:"+mimetype+";base64,"+b64encoded;
            }
        };
        oReq.send(null);
        // image_html += get_image(element.id);
    });
    
}
```